# Inside \ExplSyntaxOn/Off pair, \tl_set_rescan:Nnn gobbles every space input as ~

Tags: expl3, catcodes

Inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `~` tilde char is set to have category code of 10 (space). But then `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` gobbles every space input as `~`.

- If category code of space char is restored to 10 and then use  to input space, then it works fine.
- If category code of other char, for example dot char `.` is changed to 10 and then use this char to input space, the same problem appears.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% case 1, use ~, every space is gobbled
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \x {} { ~ a ~ b ~ }
|\x| % print "|ab|"

% case 2, restore catcode of space char
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ }
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \x {} { a b }
|\x| % print "| a b |"
\group_end:

% case 3, set catcode of . to 10
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_space:n {`\.}
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \x {} { . a . b . }
|\x| % print "|ab|"
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's expected.

As soon as a space is tokenized, for instance when a token list is formed for determining the argument to a command, space tokens are normalized with character code 32 and category code 10.

How does “rescanning” work? You have to think as if a virtual file is created and input, which TeX tokenizes again with the current category code array in force (the second argument to `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` can contain code for changing the category codes). So a `~` in the input is read in as a space, which under `\ExplSyntaxOn` is 9 (ignored).

If you want to preserve spaces upon rescanning you can do

```
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ } } { ~ a ~ b ~ }
\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
```

that will output on the terminal

```
The token list \l_tmpa_tl contains the tokens:
>    (blank space  )
>  a (the letter a)
>    (blank space  )
>  b (the letter b)
>    (blank space  ).
```

Comment: So in my original example, `~` is first normalized with character code 32 and category code 10, resulting a normal space char in the virtual file. Then, while rescanning, this normal space is ignored since `\ExplSyntaxOn` sets `\char_set_catcode_ignore:n { 32 } % space`. Am I right?

Comment: @JohannesZ Yes, I think so. AFAIK, the “virtual file” comes from the `\tl_to_str:n` (aka `\detokenize`) mentioned in `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`'s documentation.

Comment: @frougon No, the virtual file comes from the `\scantokens` primitive.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, then is it correct that `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`'s documentation mentions `\tl_to_str:n`?

Comment: @frougon The argument is first stringified because otherwise control sequences would remain unmodified with `\scantokens`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. So, can we grossly summarize `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` as follows? 1) Run `\tl_to_str:n` on the third arg. 2) Apply catcode setup from second arg. 3) Do `\tl_set:No 〈first_arg〉 \scantokens{〈output of step 1〉}`. (this after a quick look at the source code and disregarding all the subtleties handled in `\__tl_set_rescan:nNN`: `\newlinechar` being present or not, etc.).

Comment: @frougon I believe that's the idea.

Comment: @frougon For "multiline token lists" (ones which contain a `\newlinechar`) that's basically it (plus grabbing the scanned tokens with a delimited macro). For single line token lists there is an additional <s>black magic</s> trickery to preserve spaces at both ends of the token list.

Comment: Thanks Phelype. Yes, that's pretty hairy code. @egreg Sorry for being dumb, but I still don't understand the argument you gave [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524741/inside-explsyntaxon-off-pair-tl-set-rescannnn-gobbles-every-space-input-as/524744?noredirect=1#comment1327382_524744). My reading of the e-TeX manual says `\scantokens` already does some kind of string conversion before reading from the virtual file (the sketch using classical TeX does `\immediate\write0{\the\toks0}`, which would stringify control sequences). Trying stuff myself, I see the same output from...

Comment: @egreg `\def\foo{bla}X\begingroup
\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=-1
\scantokens{\foo b}X\endgroup\bye` and `\def\foo{bla}X\begingroup
\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=-1
\scantokens\expandafter{\detokenize{\foo}b}X\endgroup\bye`, and that does not surprise me. I don't pretend I understand all the implementation of `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`, but the only thing I see that justifies the `\tl_to_str:n` is the test against `\char_generate:nn { \tex_newlinechar:D } { 12 }` in `\__tl_set_rescan:nNN `.

Comment: @egreg *That* requires tokens with `\newlinechar` charcode coming from `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`'s third argument  to have catcode 12 in order to be detected by the test, and the `\tl_to_str:n` normally ensures this is the case. But I don't see why `\tl_to_str:n` helps with control sequences. In which way do they need to be modified? Thanks.